# Increment a value by previous element in R

Tags: r, vector

Say I want to create a vector with 26 values with my starting value being 6. And I want to increase by the previous value plus some arbitrary value (say 8), i.e

```
6
14 (6+8)
22 (14+8) 
30
38
.
.
.
```

Comment: `seq(from = 6, by = 8, length.out = 26)`

Answer (score 2):

We can get the `diff` and add

```
c(v1[1], v1[-length(v1)] + diff(v1))
#[1]  6 14 22 30 38
```

---

The above is general one that checks the next value to get the output.  But, if we are interested only in a fixed increment, use `rep`

```
6 + rep(0:4)*8
#[1]  6 14 22 30 38
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(6, 14, 22, 30, 38)
```

Comment: As this answer original and provides **new solution** to the linked post, I think it is better if you delete this one, and post it to the linked post?